# Upload images before form submit Django

Tags: django, database, image-uploading

I want to upload images Facebook style: select the images before submitting the form and when they are all uploaded, submit the form instantly. I know how to do it in the frontend, but the problem is in the backend. I have found some ways of managing the images in the backend but I'm not satisfied. The great deal of all this is avoiding to store the photos that won't be used, like if the user closes the browser while some photos are already uploaded. I have in mind 3 ways of doing the upload and I don't know which would be the best:

1. Create a "tmp" directory and place all the uploaded photos there, and when the form is submitted move all the used photos to another directory. (With this method there can be some concurrency problems)
2. Create a TempPhoto table in my database and do the same as the previous solution, moving the used photos from TempPhoto to the permanent table.
3. Add the photos directly to the permanent table and erase the ones that are not used (that are not related to other entity) at a scheduled time. (I suppose this would be the slower solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first way with some reformations is the best way. You can create a `tmp` directory and attach a unique data (e.g. IP address) to each image that takes control on concurrency and then write some script in `$(window).unload(...)` for send a signal to the backend that remove the image(s) from `tmp` directory when user close window before submitting the form.

Comment: That way there's still problems of concurrency with a single user, imagine a user uploads many photos so fast that the same unique id is generated (e.g IP + "1"). How can I handle this in Django? The second way I mentioned in my post handles concurrency, you discarded it because is slower to move table entries between tables than photos between directories?

Comment: Actually you can make it more unique by add some extra data (e.g. image hash value or auto incremental ID). And the answer for your question in the comment is YES. I think the process is going to be more slower when deal with database than using `tmp` directory.